# how to play custom sound for alarm in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alarms

I want to create **alarm application** for flutter with a functionality that user can choose the **custom alarm sound** that are uploaded on **firebase storage**. how can I achieve this ?

I have tried using some packages but some of them does not support custom sound and others only support asset sounds but I want to get sound from network is it possible if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Google Search results in #1 result : https://flutteragency.com/play-custom-sound-in-flutter/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).